# passing model to _layout.cshtml

Tags: jquery, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have login page that looks like

[image]

It has a ViewModelBase & a ViewModel as

```
public abstract class UserViewModelBase
{
    private string userId;

    private LdapDirectory ldapDir;

    private XXXPerson userDetails;

    public UserViewModelBase()
    {
        ldapDir = new LdapDirectory();

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            userDetails = ldapDir.GetUser(UserId, DirectoryInfoDepth.Roles);
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return userDetails.FirstName;
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return userDetails.LastName;
        }
    }

    public string Country
    {
        get
        {
            return userDetails.Country;
        }
    }

    public bool CanViewXXX
    {
        get 
        { 
            return true; //Will call an API to get values 
        }
    }

    public bool CanViewRequiredXXX
    {
        get
        {
            return true; //Will call an API to get values
        }
    }

    public bool CanViewActualXXX
    {
        get { return true; } //Will call an API to get values
    }

    public bool CanViewReports
    {
        get { return true; } //Will call an API to get values
    }

    public bool CanViewAggregations
    {
        get { return true; } //Will call an API to get values
    }

    public bool CanViewSystemParameter
    {
        get { return true; } //Will call an API to get values
    }

    public string PreferedReportFormat { get; set; }

    public string PreferedEmailId { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel : UserViewModelBase
{
    public bool IsValid(string userName, string password)
    {
        LdapDirectory ldapDir = new LdapDirectory();

        if (ldapDir.AuthenticateUser(userName, password))
        {
            var userDetails = ldapDir.GetUser(userName, DirectoryInfoDepth.Roles);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userDetails.Uid, false);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
}
```

Controller as:

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
{
    // GET: Account/Account
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(ViewModel.UserViewModel user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (user.IsValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "SystemParameter", new { area = "SystemParameter" });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        ViewModel.UserViewModel xUser = new ViewModel.UserViewModel();
        xUser.Logout();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new { area = "Account" });
    }
}
```

Login.cshtml as

```
    @model XXX.Areas.Account.ViewModel.UserViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>XXX - Login - @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppVersion"]</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#UserName").on("keypress", function () {
                //$(this).parent().find('div[class=popover]').html("");
                $("[data-valmsg-for=UserName]").html("");
            });

            $("#Password").on("keypress", function () {
                $(this).parent().find('div[class=popover]').remove();
                //$(this).parent().find('div[class=popover]').html("");
                $("[data-valmsg-for=Password]").html("");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">XXX</div>
                    <div style="float:right;  position: relative; top:-20px">Log In</div>
                </div>

                <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body">

                    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "loginForm", @role = "form" }))
                    {

                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName, new { @id = "login-username", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "User Name", @data_toggle = "popover", @data_placement = "top" })

                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName)

                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password, new { @id = "login-password", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password", @data_toggle = "popover", @data_placement = "top" })

                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)

                        <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                <button type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-primary btn-success">Log In</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px;">
                                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now after login user is redirected to one of the main page of the site that has a _Layout file.

```
@model XXX.Areas.Account.ViewModel.UserViewModelBase

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>XXX - @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppVersion"]</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/jqwidgets")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqwidgets")

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#userPreferences").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").html('<img src="../Styles/images/CircularProgressAnimation.gif" alt="Please wait..." />');
                $("#dialog").css("display", "");//show the dialog div
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    dragable: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: this.title,
                    modal: true,
                    width: Math.min(450, $(window).width() * .8),
                    position: {
                        my: "center top",
                        at: ("center top+" + ($(window).height() * .1)),
                        collision: "none"
                    },
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        //Load the UserPreferences action which will return the partial view UserPreferences
                        $(this).load('/Common/UserPreferences' + "?t=" + new Date().getTime());
                    },
                    close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('destroy').html('');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            @*Class container must be modified as per need*@
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("XXX", "Login", "Account", new { area = "Account" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"  id="MainMenu" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @if (Model.CanViewXXX)
                    {
                    <li class="dropdown">@Html.ActionLink("View XXX", "Index", "View", new { area = "View" }, null)</li>
                    }
                    @if (Model.CanViewRequiredXXX)
                    {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Required XXX", "Index", "Required", new { area = "Required" }, null)</li>
                    }
                    @if (Model.CanViewActualXXX)
                    {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Actual XXX", "Index", "Actual", new { area = "Actual" }, null)</li>
                    }
                    @if (Model.CanViewReports)
                    {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Index", "Report", new { area = "Report" }, null)</li>
                    }
                    @if (Model.CanViewAggregations)
                    {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Aggregations", "Index", "Aggregation", new { area = "Aggregation" }, null)</li>
                    }
                    @if (Model.CanViewSystemParameter)
                    {
                    <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("XXX Parameters", "Index", "SystemParameter", new { area = "SystemParameter" }, null)</li>
                    }
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                            <strong>
                                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                                {
                                @Model.UserId
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                @: Hello!!!
                                }
                            </strong>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <div class="navbar-login">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <p class="text-center">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon-size"></span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                                            <p class="text-left small"><strong>Name:</strong> @Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</p>
                                            <p class="text-left small"><strong>Country:</strong> @Model.Country</p>
                                            <p class="text-left small"><strong>Prefered E-mail:</strong> @Model.PreferedEmailId</p>
                                            <p class="text-left small"><strong>Prefered Reporting Format:</strong> @Model.PreferedReportFormat</p>
                                            <p class="text-left">
                                                <a id="userPreferences" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm">User Preference</a>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="navbar-login navbar-login-session">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <p>
                                                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                                                {
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOut", "Account", new { area = "Account" }, null)
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Log In", "Login", "Account", new { area = "Account" }, null)
                                                }
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="dialog" title="User Preferences" style="display:none">
    </div>
    <div id="shadowBox" style="display: none;">
        <img src="../Styles/images/CircularProgressAnimation.gif" alt="Please wait..." />
    </div>
    @RenderSection("viewScripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

It has a menu option as

[image]

where userid is displayed and opening it displays a partial view as

[image]

Controller for this is

```
public class SystemParameterController : Controller
    {
        // GET: SystemParameter/SystemParameter
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            decimal emailIdKey = 2;
            decimal reportFormatKey = 1;

            var user = new Account.ViewModel.UserViewModel();

            using (var userPreferencesDB = new Models.UserPreferencesDbContext())
            {
                var userPreferences = userPreferencesDB.DWP_USER_PREF_T.Where(u => u.USER_ID.Equals(user.UserId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
                var excelFormats = userPreferencesDB.DWP_REP_FORMAT_T.ToList();

                if (userPreferences.Count > 0)
                {
                    user.PreferedEmailId = userPreferences.Where(u => u.PREF_KEY == emailIdKey).SingleOrDefault().PREF_VALUE;
                    var reportFormatId = userPreferences.Where(u => u.PREF_KEY == reportFormatKey).SingleOrDefault().PREF_VALUE;
                    user.PreferedReportFormat = excelFormats.Where(e => e.FORMAT_ID.ToString() == reportFormatId).SingleOrDefault().REP_FORMAT;
                }
                else
                {
                    user.PreferedEmailId = user.UserId.ToLower() + "@yyy.com";
                    user.PreferedReportFormat = excelFormats.Where(e => e.FORMAT_ID.ToString() == "1").SingleOrDefault().REP_FORMAT;
                }
            }

            return View(user);
        }
    }
```

On click of User Preference following opens

[image]

using controller

```
public class CommonController : Controller
    {
        public PartialViewResult UserPreferences()
        {
            decimal emailIdKey = 2;
            decimal reportFormatKey = 1;

            var userPreferenceVM = new ViewModels.UserPreferenceViewModel();

            using (var userPreferencesDB = new Models.UserPreferencesDbContext())
            {
                var userPreferences = userPreferencesDB.XXX_USER_PREF_T.Where(u => u.USER_ID.Equals(userPreferenceVM.UserId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
                var excelFormats = userPreferenceVM.Format = userPreferencesDB.XXX_REP_FORMAT_T.ToList();

                if (userPreferences.Count > 0)
                {
                    userPreferenceVM.PreferedEmailId = userPreferences.Where(u => u.PREF_KEY == emailIdKey).SingleOrDefault().PREF_VALUE;
                    var reportFormatId = userPreferences.Where(u => u.PREF_KEY == reportFormatKey).SingleOrDefault().PREF_VALUE;
                    userPreferenceVM.PreferedReportFormat = excelFormats.Where(e => e.FORMAT_ID.ToString() == reportFormatId).SingleOrDefault().REP_FORMAT;
                }
                else
                {
                    userPreferenceVM.PreferedEmailId = userPreferenceVM.UserId.ToLower() + "@yyy.com";
                    userPreferenceVM.PreferedReportFormat = excelFormats.Where(e => e.FORMAT_ID.ToString() == "1").SingleOrDefault().REP_FORMAT;
                }
            }

            return PartialView(userPreferenceVM);
        }
    }
```

Now the questions...

1) Is UserViewModelBase & UserViewModel the correct approach to go for displaying login, User Preferences and Edit User Preference. I mean what to add in UserViewModelBase & what to add in UserViewModel.

2) I am using two different Actions to display User Preferences as partial view and Edit User Preferences as view. Is that ok or something needs to be corrected here.

It's like I somehow am not liking this. It seems like redoing work rather than reusing it.

Let me know what suggestions r there and what improvements I can make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented a better design by converting the navigation section into a PartialView and converted UserViewModelBase and UserViewModel to User (Model) and used it with RenderAction in the _Layout page.

Now I am a bit satisfied with the implementation.